# Similar methods return different results

Tags: python, parentheses

I have 2 methods that are both supposed to return `(20, 15, 3, 0, 7, -50)`, but the second method returns `(20, 15, 3, 0, 7, -200)`. It probably has to do with the order of variables, but i have tried changing it and they still don't return the same answer.

Code:

```
def method1():
    a = 10
    b = 3
    c = 2
    d = 5
    e = 5
    f = -30
    f, b, c, d, e, a = (2*a+f)*e, b*e, c+1, (a*(7*c+2)+f*e)//(b*e), e+2, a*c
    return (a,b,c,d,e,f)
def method2():
    a = 10
    b = 3
    c = 2
    d = 5
    e = 5
    f = -30
    g,h,i,j,k,l = a,b,c,d,e,f
    d = (g*(7*i+2)+l*k)//(h*k)
    f = 2*(g+l)*k
    a = g*i
    b = h*k
    c = i+1
    e = k + 2
    return (a,b,c,d,e,f)
```

Comment: Typo - you moved the parentheses between `(2*a+f)*e` and `2*(g+l)*k`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the confusion. The problem is the parenthesis in `method2` when calculating f variable:

```
f = 2*(g+l)*k
```

which, according to your code logic is mathematically equal to:

```
f = 2*(a+f)*e
```

This makes `a+f` then multiplies by `2` then `k`. On `method1` you make:

```
f = (2*a+f)*e
```

Which makes `2*a` then sums `f` then multiplies the result by `e`. The mathematical operations are similar on both methods but they are different!